# Reset UIScrollView contentOffset during CoreAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-animation

I have a `UIScrollView` that is vertically scrolled with coreAnimation as follows:

```
 - (void) scrollAnimation
{
    CGRect bounds = scrollview.bounds;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:bounds];

    bounds.origin.y += 1000;

    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:bounds];

    [scrollview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bounds"];

    scrollview.bounds = bounds;
}
```

The actual height of the `scrollView` is less than the total animation, so I wish to reset the `contentOffset` to 0 when the scrollview reaches the end of its height, and continue the animation seamlessly.

When I try to do this within

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 600)
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    }
}
```

The method doesn't seem to get called during the animation. The same happens when trying to use a Key-Value observer on the `scrollView`, the method gets called just fine when scrolling manually, but not during the `coreAnimation`. Using an `NSTimer` method to check periodically also proved fruitless.

How can I get the `contentOffset` (or `scrollview.bounds`) during a `coreAnimation`, and reset it?
I wish to animate the `scrollView` so that the contents (several `UILabels`) scroll seamlessly over an animation that is greater than the content size.

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollViews don't actually change their offset during animations. If you want to "reset" the offset I would suggest figuring out how to end your animation at the correct time and set the bounds afterwards.

You can also use UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:animated:` method. You you won't have as much control over the animation but you will get notified when it scrolls and when it is finished.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. And yet, during regular scrolling from a touch event (even while the momentum scrolling is going on) these values are accessible? What would be the easiest way to accomplish this sort of animation ie. a vertical scrolling number ticker? I am currently considering animating it by very small linear values at a time, and calculating duration values via an easing function, but this does not seem like the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: UIScrollView is really not built for this. You can take a look at some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675535/how-to-implement-cyclic-scrolling-on-tableview but I don't think you will end up with a great solution.