# How to get middle cell of horizontal table view in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have rotated my table view by 90°. Now I want to get indexpath of middle cell. When table view is not scrolling, it is showing 3 cells. What I want is, when table view stops scrolling, it should middle cell of green color. Sometimes I get wrong indexpath when more then 3 cells are visible while fast scrolling.
I have attached image for reference[image: This is my horizontal table view and I want to show green color for middle cell]

Comment: Are you seriously using a table view?  Why aren't you using a collection view?

Comment: @nhgrif , actually it a infinite scrolling table view. I have used following link for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404116/uitableview-infinite-scrolling and answer given by Frank Gorman. Now at the end of project, we can not change approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
NSIndexPath *middleIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(tableView.center.y, tableView.center.x)];

UITableViewCell *middleCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:middleIndexPath];
```

Comment: It is always giving 0. May be because table is rotated.

Comment: CGPointMake(tableView.center.x, tableView.center.y) try this

Answer (score 0):

You can get contentOffset of table view. With contentOffset, you can calculate current row (contentOffset.y / row height)