# how to do endless loading in iphone app like facebook with chunks of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

is there any way to do like Facebook loading that i have one array having 100 objects and on screen 10 cell display.what i want is when i scroll want loading at footer and another 10 data should come and so on...i tried too much but couldn't find this.
Data is come from WebService and i am taking it to an array.

Also is this possible that when i scroll and goes to bottom of the tableview it automatically display 10 new cell without reload all table.

i tried this but not success

```
 if (indexPath.row == [newsArray count] - 1)
            [self News_WS_Called];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404116/uitableview-infinite-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using [UIScrollViewDelegate's scrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html) method. I basically see if the view is scrolled to the bottom and then call the method that handles fetching more, appending to data source and reloading the tableview. Here's a very basic example:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{    
    CGRect mainRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - mainRect.size.height){
      // at the bottom of the scroll view
       [self News_WS_Called];
    }
}
```

Something things to consider is that you will need some kind of mutex so that the reload / fetch code does not repeatedly get called or gets called when there is nothing on the table view.

Comment: this code will working are you sure brother i have doubt because data is already come in array(web service is already called in view will appear method).is there any need to call web service again?

Comment: I am not sure what your method "News_WS_Called" does.. You will need to call the web service again because you need to fetch the next set of items with the give LIMIT and OFFSET.