# Smooth Scroll in UITableview to show chat history

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am working on Chat application. I have a View Controller to display the messages in a tableview. On selecting a particular chat I will fetch 12 recent message & reload the table and scroll it to bottom so that user can see the recent message(index 11).
As user starts scrolling up (as he reaches to 0th index) I need to fetch the history through a web service and display it on UI smoothly in the same order.

Code for displaying the cell

```
cell = STBubbleTableViewCell.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
cell.backgroundColor = self.chatTableView?.backgroundColor
cell.selectionStyle = .None
cell.dataSource = self
cell.delegate = self

let chat = chatMessages[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
cell.textLabel?.text = chat.message
if(self.isGroupChat)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = NSString.init(format: "%@ %@", chat.authorName, chat.messageDate.toShortTimeString()) as String
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = chat.messageDate.toShortTimeString()
}

cell.authorType = chat.authorType == 0 ? AuthorType.STBubbleTableViewCellAuthorTypeSelf : AuthorType.STBubbleTableViewCellAuthorTypeOther

cell.bubbleColor = chat.bubbleType == 0 ? BubbleColor.STBubbleTableViewCellBubbleColorGreen : BubbleColor.STBubbleTableViewCellBubbleColorGray
```

Code for fetching chat history

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    pointNow = scrollView.contentOffset
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < pointNow.y)
    {
        self.fetchChatHistory()
    }
}
```

self.fetchChatHistory is getting called multiple times. How to avoid this multiple calls?

Comment: Did you checked? https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: I haven't  used JSQMessageViewController. I have used STTableviewCell to show the messages in my tableview.

Comment: what are you trying to obtain with scrollViewWillBeginDragging and scrollViewDidEndDragging calls?

Comment: I am invoking a web service and getting the chat history

Answer (score 0):

Using scrollViewWillBeginDragging and scrollViewDidEndDragging calls, you call fetching on each scroll, whatever the user has not reached the end of the table.
Instead you need to implement tableview infinite scrolling:

give it a look: [UITableView infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404116/uitableview-infinite-scrolling)